# AngularJS $location change promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am using angularJS $location service for routing change, 
the problem is `$location.url(someUrl)` is asynchronous but doesn't return promise.

So I searched for some solution for this and found these events:

1. `$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess')`
2. `$routeChangeStart`
3. `$routeChangeSuccess`

but these events not happening for example when the URL provided to `$location.url` function is the same as current, 
I'm seeking for some robust solution to be ensured that `$location.url` has finished it's work

Comment: what do you want to achieve by using this service please elaborate?

Comment: @AbuSufian I'm using $location service for routing and changing view/pages in my app. I need to do another action when the page was fully replaced

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$timeout` service:

```
$location.url(someUrl);

var promise = $timeout();
```

The promise will resolve after the framework has collected all the calls to the $location service and the browser has rendered the new url.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: how can you know that the route has ended, it could take more than the timeout interval, for example for heave pages with a lot of data to load